# Sqlite Collation with EF Core

Tags: ef-core-5.0, ef-core-6.0

I can define a text column collation on Sql Server as follows as [shown here in the Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#column-collation)

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(c => c.Name)
    .UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");
```

The string here **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** is specific to Sql Server.

But what if I want the same with Sqlite or some other database for that matter.

Where do I get that info from?

What is the equivalent of **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** in Sqlite for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQLite there are only a few collations to choose from.

- BINARY
- NOCASE
- RTRIM

see for details https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: Just to add, more can be added as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/collation